# iMacros nested loop for performing task and jumping to next page on completion

Tags: imacros

Macro 1 is performing a task 10 times on a page - I have that covered. Then once the task has been completed I need Macro 2 to jump to the next page (that is also done) and let Macro 1 do its thing again - that's where I have a problem. I'll do this jumping to the next page a predefined number of times, for example 20 times, hence the `!LOOP 20`. I can't figure out how to programatically do the nesting of the two macros. I know it should be done in JS and I have done both macros in JS - I just don't know how to "tell" that once Macro 1 is done it should execute Macro 2 and jump to the next page and start Macro 1 again.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var macro1;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=000000" + "\n";
macro += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:***" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=TXT:*** CONTENT=***" + "\n";
for(var i=0;i<11;i++)
{
iimDisplay(i);
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(macro1);}

var macro2 = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !LOOP 20" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next<SP>›" + "\n";
{
iimPlay(macro2);}
```

Comment: Apply `for`-loops and `if`-clauses in the js-script. (Or provide your code to get less general answers.)

Comment: Done - added a more detailed description including the code I have so far.

Answer (score 1):

So try this:

```
var macro1 =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
// macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=000000" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:***" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=TXT:*** CONTENT=***" + "\n";

var macro2 = "CODE:";
// macro2 += "SET !LOOP 20" + "\n";
macro2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next<SP>›" + "\n";

for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++ ) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        iimDisplay(i);
        iimSet("i", i);
        iimPlay(macro1);
    }
    iimPlay(macro2);
}
```